# Как в php экранировать спец символы json?

Tags: php, json

Например коментарии выводятся через json. Но нарушается система если пользователь добавляет комментарий содержащий json строку. В php есть ли специальная функция для экранирования спец символов json ? Если нету спец функция то я уверен что данная проблема уже решена и вы подскажете мне самый лучший вариант проверенный временем

Comment: Чем не устраивает работа функции json_encode() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php ?

Comment: `самый лучший вариант проверенный временем` :))) . `$str = str_replace("символ", "\символ", $output);`. И действительно,верно товарищ подметил, `json_encode`

Comment: Что подразумевается под "нарушается система"? С примерами, пожалуйста

Comment: 1. Причем тут json_encode ?

Comment: 2. Да это вариант

Comment: 3. Система такая: js с сервера загружает Json строку коментариев и парсит. Потом отображает комменты. Но что если пользователь добавляет комментарий содержащий json строку.  Тогда при парсинге парсится и тот json код которого добавил пользователь! Вот так система нарушается. По этому ищу способ как в php экранировать спец символы json. Давайте привожу пример где все норм: ["comment text"] теперь посмотрим что будет если пользователь добавляет комментарий содержащий json строку: ["{"bla":"4"}"]

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется, "спец функция" есть. Называется `json_encode()`. Любое создание  JSON должно производиться не чумазыми косолапыми ручками, **а только этой функцией.** А все спецсимволы эта функция отформатирует сама, причем сделает это **правильно**, и в **полном объеме**.

**Пример №1:**

```
$comments = [
    "comment text1",
    "коммент текст2",
    "comment text3",
];
echo json_encode($comments, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

выведет нам

```
["comment text1","коммент текст2","comment text3"]
```

Флаги `JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR`и `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` являются наиболее полезными, их имеет смысл добавлять по умолчанию.

**Пример №2:**

предположим, пользователь ввел в комментарий JSON строку:

```
$comments = [
    '{"bla":"4"}',
];
echo json_encode($comments, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

выведет нам

```
["{\"bla\":\"4\"}"]
```

Как видно, все спецсиволы тут УЖЕ прекрасно отформатированы, и принимающая сторона, раскодируя принятые комментарии, никогда не воспримет этот текст как JSON, а воспримет как простую строку.

Answer (score 1):

Для экранирования специальных символов в JSON в PHP вы можете использовать функцию json_encode(). Эта функция преобразует данные в формат JSON и автоматически экранирует специальные символы.

```
$string = 'Hello "world"';
$json = json_encode($string);
echo $json;
```