# Как вы экрануете спец символы json в php?

Tags: json

Система такая: js с сервера загружает Json строку коментариев и парсит. Потом отображает комменты. Но что если пользователь добавляет комментарий содержащий json строку. Тогда при парсинге парсится и тот json код которого добавил пользователь! Вот так система нарушается. По этому ищу способ как в php экранировать спец символы json. Давайте привожу пример где все норм: ["comment text"] теперь посмотрим что будет если пользователь добавляет комментарий содержащий json строку: ["{"bla":"4"}"]

Comment: Дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671438/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-php-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-json

Comment: @Dance посмотрите функцию php  addcslashes, Как я вижу это вам должно помочь, он экранирует строку.
Вот пример <?php
echo addcslashes('foo[ ]', 'A..z');
// выводит:  \f\o\o\[ \]
// Будут экранированы заглавные и строчные английские буквы
// ... а также [\]^_`
?>